# Is there is a design problem or documentation problem with FirstCase?

Tags: list-manipulation, version-10

In version 10 the new function `FirstCase` can take up to 4 arguments (plus option). The third argument is a default value to be returned if there is no match:

[image]

Toward the end of the examples in Scope is an example is given in which the third argument is actually the level spec and all matches to the pattern are returned, not just the first match:

[image]

However when you evaluate the docs you actually get what is expected based on the function definition, namely that since there are no matches at the default first level a default value of `{2}` (presumably intended to be a level spec) is returned:

[image]

The very next example in the docs also has a level spec as the third argument.

I'm not sure how the docs output was obtained but would others agree that there is a bug in the documentation?

(I'm on OS X 10.9.4 using 10.0.0.0)

Comment: I would agree...

Comment: There are lots an lots of bugs in the documentation.

Comment: Reported as a documentation error. (As for how it was obtained, I believe there was a time during not-so-distant development when the default value was handled as an option instead of optional argument.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to have been a documentation error because the examples in v10.0.1 are now more sensible:

[image: documentation screenshot]